# How to get email from a "__privaterelay.appleid.com" address so you can confirm something using iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, apple-id

I signed up for a retail app and I get free stuff, but I have to respond to their email that went to a privaterelay.appleid.com address instead of my regular one.

Q. how can I get this email that was sent?  I have about 3 email accounts, how can I verify which one it is sending anything to?

I already checked the mail app on the iPhone.

iPhone, iOS 16

Answer (score 4):

The email is forwarded to your Apple ID contact email. It will appear in your inbox or junk folder like any other email.

If it doesn't appear and resending does not work, verify in iCloud Settings > Hide My Email that you haven't disabled this address. You can also confirm where it's forwarding.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/create-and-manage-hide-my-email-addresses-iphcb02e76f7/ios

[image]